# Easiest way to convert key codes into strings representing keys?

Tags: javascript, keypress

I am using the following event listener to capture keypresses:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {} );
```

What is the easiest way to get a string which represents the key pressed, like the value of 33 would be "Pg Up", 84 would be "F5", 40 would be "Down Arrow" etc... Is there some useful javascript library for this?

Comment: Those aren't Unicode values, those are key codes. There's no Unicode value for the "letters" F5 or PgUp.

Comment: Try using a library like Mousetrap.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This website has a list. It seems it would be pretty easy to convert it to a set of constants or place it into an array.

http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Codes are for US keyboards. In fact, if you just steal their js...

```
 var keyPressed;
 if (charCode == 8) keyPressed = "backspace"; //  backspace
 if (charCode == 9) keyPressed = "tab"; //  tab
 if (charCode == 13) keyPressed = "enter"; //  enter
 if (charCode == 16) keyPressed = "shift"; //  shift
 if (charCode == 17) keyPressed = "ctrl"; //  ctrl
 if (charCode == 18) keyPressed = "alt"; //  alt
 if (charCode == 19) keyPressed = "pause/break"; //  pause/break
 if (charCode == 20) keyPressed = "caps lock"; //  caps lock
 if (charCode == 27) keyPressed = "escape"; //  escape
 if (charCode == 33) keyPressed = "page up"; // page up, to avoid displaying alternate character and confusing people
 if (charCode == 34) keyPressed = "page down"; // page down
 if (charCode == 35) keyPressed = "end"; // end
 if (charCode == 36) keyPressed = "home"; // home
 if (charCode == 37) keyPressed = "left arrow"; // left arrow
 if (charCode == 38) keyPressed = "up arrow"; // up arrow
 if (charCode == 39) keyPressed = "right arrow"; // right arrow
 if (charCode == 40) keyPressed = "down arrow"; // down arrow
 if (charCode == 45) keyPressed = "insert"; // insert
 if (charCode == 46) keyPressed = "delete"; // delete
 if (charCode == 91) keyPressed = "left window"; // left window
 if (charCode == 92) keyPressed = "right window"; // right window
 if (charCode == 93) keyPressed = "select key"; // select key
 if (charCode == 96) keyPressed = "numpad 0"; // numpad 0
 if (charCode == 97) keyPressed = "numpad 1"; // numpad 1
 if (charCode == 98) keyPressed = "numpad 2"; // numpad 2
 if (charCode == 99) keyPressed = "numpad 3"; // numpad 3
 if (charCode == 100) keyPressed = "numpad 4"; // numpad 4
 if (charCode == 101) keyPressed = "numpad 5"; // numpad 5
 if (charCode == 102) keyPressed = "numpad 6"; // numpad 6
 if (charCode == 103) keyPressed = "numpad 7"; // numpad 7
 if (charCode == 104) keyPressed = "numpad 8"; // numpad 8
 if (charCode == 105) keyPressed = "numpad 9"; // numpad 9
 if (charCode == 106) keyPressed = "multiply"; // multiply
 if (charCode == 107) keyPressed = "add"; // add
 if (charCode == 109) keyPressed = "subtract"; // subtract
 if (charCode == 110) keyPressed = "decimal point"; // decimal point
 if (charCode == 111) keyPressed = "divide"; // divide
 if (charCode == 112) keyPressed = "F1"; // F1
 if (charCode == 113) keyPressed = "F2"; // F2
 if (charCode == 114) keyPressed = "F3"; // F3
 if (charCode == 115) keyPressed = "F4"; // F4
 if (charCode == 116) keyPressed = "F5"; // F5
 if (charCode == 117) keyPressed = "F6"; // F6
 if (charCode == 118) keyPressed = "F7"; // F7
 if (charCode == 119) keyPressed = "F8"; // F8
 if (charCode == 120) keyPressed = "F9"; // F9
 if (charCode == 121) keyPressed = "F10"; // F10
 if (charCode == 122) keyPressed = "F11"; // F11
 if (charCode == 123) keyPressed = "F12"; // F12
 if (charCode == 144) keyPressed = "num lock"; // num lock
 if (charCode == 145) keyPressed = "scroll lock"; // scroll lock
 if (charCode == 186) keyPressed = ";"; // semi-colon
 if (charCode == 187) keyPressed = "="; // equal-sign
 if (charCode == 188) keyPressed = ","; // comma
 if (charCode == 189) keyPressed = "-"; // dash
 if (charCode == 190) keyPressed = "."; // period
 if (charCode == 191) keyPressed = "/"; // forward slash
 if (charCode == 192) keyPressed = "`"; // grave accent
 if (charCode == 219) keyPressed = "["; // open bracket
 if (charCode == 220) keyPressed = "\\"; // back slash
 if (charCode == 221) keyPressed = "]"; // close bracket
 if (charCode == 222) keyPressed = "'"; // single quote  var lblCharCode = getObject('spnCode');
```